# Latency due to a high GPU usage or throttling is possible?

Tags: latency

I'm currently using a Ryzen 3700X and an Vega 64. My problem is related to audio and videos, which suttles and freezes.

I downloaded the LatencyMon, and they say that "Your system appears to be having trouble handling real-time audio and other tasks". The main problem comes from: "ntoskrnl.exe" and "wdf01000.sys". Have some other like "atikmdag.sys", "ndis.sys", "rcraid.sys" and "dxgkrnl.sys" always had a high execution time.

---

After many tests: I notice that the latency spikes when the GPU is a full load for some time, exactly when the GPU comes closer to 85 
Celsius degree.

So, I have two kind of questions:

1. Could the high GPU usage causes the latency (wish also impact the audio, even when I use a external DAC, rather than the AMD audio)?
2. Could the throttling from the GPU, due to the high temperature, cause the latency?